# Питоновский виджет для отображение html файла

Tags: python, google-maps-api, tkinter, виджет

Нужно написать програму на Python, в которой будет отображаться Google Maps.
При помощи Maps JavaScript API реализуется настройка карты которая сохраняется в html файле. 
Как отобразить html файл не в браузере, а в десктопном приложении? 
Какой виджет использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте [pywebview](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pywebview/0.5)

Это конечно не  tkinter, а GTK и pyQt (4 и 5) - выбирает из доступного.

Установка

```
apt install gir1.2-webkit-3.0 python3-pip
pip3 install pywebview
```

Пример

```
import webview
webview.create_window("It works, Jim!", "./index.html")
```

Comment: То что надо. Спасибо))

Comment: Библиотеку pywebview можно использовать вместе pyQt5 верно?

Comment: Эта штука перебирает gtk,qt4,qt5 и открывает в том окне, что найдет первым. Можно покапаться и принудить к кутэ5

Comment: как сделать эту штуку виджетом, что бы к нему можно было добавить еще пару графических елементов?

Comment: Копай в сторону pyqt, pyside, gtk, wx. там этот элемент есть виджетом.

Comment: https://github.com/r0x0r/pywebview/blob/master/webview/qt.py#L105

Comment: на первоначальный вопрос ответ довольно полный. задайте новый вопрос